# use $_GET['']; value inside $_POST[''] and submit it to the same page and display in the same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i am new to php and while i am practing i came across a problem. actually,i have two files index1.php and index2.php. in index1.php i have a link with a unique id as

```
<a href="index2.php?companyid=<?php echo $row('company_id');?>>details</a>
```

i have got this value in index2.php as

```
if(isset($_GET['companyid'])){
  $companyid = $_GET['companyid'];
 }
```

now i have a search form in the index2.php as

```
<form method="POST" action="index2.php">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

now on button click i want the search results be displayed in the same page as

```
'index2.php?companyid=$companyid'
```

but some how if i try to use `$_POST['submit'];` in the same page it takes me to index2.php and instead of `index2.php?companyid=$companyid` and also it throws error as `undefined index of $companyid` if i don't use `$_POST['submit'];` and `echo $companyid;` it gives value and works fine. all i want is that to use ``` $companyid' value inside ``$_POST['submit']; ``` as and display the result in the same url as before

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
  $companyid //throws an error index of company id
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You are not passing company ID in the POST request so it is not present when the new page loads. PHP is stateless. It does not remember anything between requests. In order to "remember" things, you can pass them as query string values, send them as request body parameters in a POST request, or use cookies as a storage mechanism. In your case, you probably want to keep the company ID as part of the URL's query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it looks like you are not using the company id in the form itself, so it will not be submitted as part of the the `POST`. You could possibly use:

```
<form method="POST" action="index2.php">
  <?php if (isset($companyid)): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="companyid" value="<?= $companyid; ?>">
  <?php endif; ?>
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

But you would probably also need to change your logic to:

```
if(isset($_POST['companyid'])){
  $companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
}else if(isset($_GET['companyid'])){
  $companyid = $_GET['companyid'];
}
```

Comment: Instead of the ```if```-chain you could just use ```$_REQUEST``` to cover the entire load.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, I just thought this highlighted the logic better. (But I completely agree...)

Answer (score 0):

As Josh pointed out in the comments, PHP is not able to remember your previous `GET` request but this can easily be solved by altering the `action` attribute of the `form` element. By doing this you can pass on the previous data. This would look a little something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="index2.php?companyid=<?php echo $companyid;?>">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

This way you will be redirected to `index2.php` with the URL parameters present and you will be able to retrieve both `search` and `companyid` using `$_POST` and `$_GET` or use `$_REQUEST` for both.

Comment: that helps a bit but if i try to echo the $companyid i still dont get it white clicking the button. i've done `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$id = $_GET['companyid']; echo $id;}`